# When building Scala(2.7.0) maven project getting error "error while loading Consumer" with Java 8 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

When building Scala maven project getting error:

```
error while loading Consumer, class file 'C:\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/function/Consumer.class)' is broken
```

Comment: Scala 2.7 is more than a decade old. It's unlikely to work with current JDKs, current build tools, etc. 2.11 is the oldest version still in widespread use.

Answer (score 1):

After searching find out this link(https://github.com/jboner/akka-training/issues/1) which states:

There are two ways to solve it:

**Option 1**: Using java 7 with scala 2.7.2

**Option 2:** Using another version of scala (2.11.4), and java 8:

**I tried option-2 and upgraded Scala version to 2.12.0, it worked for me.**